# Embed m4v file in a PowerPoint 2010 file

Tags: media-player, powerpoint, mp4, powerpoint-2010, m4v

I have a MP4 video file (.m4v). I can play it well in Windows Media Player on my Windows 7 computer. While I tried to embed it into my PowerPoint presentation (.pptx) it was unable to allow me to.

Any solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got it sorted. It requires a proper codec to be able play in the PowerPoint file. I installed QuickTime now it works!